# MongoDB: how to get db.stats() from API

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm trying to get results of db.stats() mongo shell command in my python code (for monitoring purposes).

But unlike for example serverStatus I can't do `db.command('stats')`. I was not able to find any API equivalent in mongodb docs. I've also tried variations with `db.$cmd` but none of that worked.

So,

Small question: how can I get results of `db.stats()` (number of connections/objects, size of data & indexes, etc) in my python code?

Bigger question: can anyone explain why some of shell commands are easily accessible from API, while others are not? It's very annoying: some admin-related tools are accessible via `db.$cmd.sys`, some via `db.command`, some via ...? Is there some standard or explanation of this situation?

PS: mongodb 2.0.2, pymongo 2.1.0, python 2.7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Javascript shell's `stats` command helper actually invokes a command named `dbstats`, which you can run from PyMongo using the [`Database.command` method](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command). The easiest way to find out what command a shell helper will run is to invoke the shell helper without parentheses -- this will print out the Javascript code it runs:

```
> db.stats
function (scale) {
    return this.runCommand({dbstats:1, scale:scale});
}
```

As for why some commands have helpers and others do not, it's largely a question of preference, time, and perceived frequency of use by the driver authors. You can run any command by name with `Database.command`, which is just a convenience wrapper around `db.$cmd.find_one`. You can find a full list of commands at [List of Database Commands](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/List+of+Database+Commands). You can also [submit a patch](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver) against PyMongo to add a helper method for commands you find that you need to invoke frequently but aren't supported by PyMongo yet.

Comment: Be warned that dbstats blocks your database while it runs, so it's not suitable in production. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5714

Comment: It's not clear this is still a blocking call in the `WiredTiger` storage engine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559408/is-db-stats-a-blocking-call-for-mongodb