# MongoDB shell's db.stats() in php and python

Tags: python, php, mongodb, pymongo, php-mongodb

I can see the statistics from Mongo shell as

```
db.stats()
```

or

```
db.collection_name.stats()
```

How do I view statistics of a database, or of a collection, from PHP and Python.

**EDIT**:
I have done it in PHP but still cant do it in Python.

Help?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how you do it in `Python` if you are using the `PyMongo` driver:

```
connection = pymongo.Connection(host = "127.0.0.1", port = 27017)
db = connection["test_db"]
test_collection = db["test_collection"]
db.command("dbstats") # prints database stats for "test_db"
db.command("collstats", "test_collection") # prints collection-level stats for "test_collection" under "test_db".
```

**References:**

[db.command()](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.command)

[MongoDB: how to get db.stats() from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726152/mongodb-how-to-get-db-stats-from-api)

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this and docs are actually accurate? I'm getting `command() missing 1 required positional argument: 'command'` no matter what I pass as an argument. Has this been deprecated and not updated in docs?

Comment: (incase anyone wants in size other than bytes, for which I struggled alot) - for passing scale you can do this: `db.command("collstats", "test_collection", scale=1024*1024)`. This will convert into MB. You can also also change it up as you like for KB, GB, etc. However, `avgObjSize` will always be in bytes.

Answer (score 9):

This is how you do it in PHP

```
$con= new Mongo()

$stats=$con->dbName->command(array('dbStats' => 1));  // for db.stats()

$stats=$con->dbName->command(array('collStats' => 'collection_name')); // for db.collection_name.stats()
```

But how to do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have found to do this with a Mongoengine model was this:

```
import mongoengine
from models import MyModel

connection = mongoengine.connection.get_connection()
db = connection[MyModel._get_db().name]
stats = db.command("collstats", MyModel._get_collection_name())
```

This should allow transparent changes in the collection and database using mongoengine's config settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP code to execute `dbStats` command with new `MongoDB` driver:

```
$mongo = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$cmdstats = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command(['dbStats' => 1]);
$dbstats = $mongo->executeCommand('databaseName', $cmdstats);
$dbstats->setTypeMap(array(
    'array' => 'array',
    'document' => 'array',
    'root' => 'array'
));

// There must be only one item in $dbstats

foreach ($dbstats as $dbs)
{
    echo($dbs['dataSize']);
}
```