# PHP MongoDB get statistics

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm currently trying to retrieve the statistics of a mongodb by php. I already found the way to run the command (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11650724/2889265), but than executing it, the response is completly different to the expected result of executing db.stats() directly on the database. Here's what I got:

Result PHP *$this->database->command(array('dbStats' => 1));*:

```
MongoDB\Driver\Cursor Object
(
    [database] => dev
    [collection] => 
    [query] => 
    [command] => MongoDB\Driver\Command Object
        (
            [command] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [dbStats] => 1
                )

        )

    [readPreference] => MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference Object
        (
            [mode] => primary
        )

    [isDead] => 
    [currentIndex] => 0
    [currentDocument] => 
    [server] => MongoDB\Driver\Server Object
        (
            [host] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
            [port] => 27017
            [type] => 1
            [is_primary] => 
            [is_secondary] => 
            [is_arbiter] => 
            [is_hidden] => 
            [is_passive] => 
            [last_is_master] => Array
                (
                    [ismaster] => 1
                    [maxBsonObjectSize] => 16777216
                    [maxMessageSizeBytes] => 48000000
                    [maxWriteBatchSize] => 1000
                    [localTime] => MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime Object
                        (
                            [milliseconds] => 1498465564742
                        )

                    [maxWireVersion] => 2
                    [minWireVersion] => 0
                    [ok] => 1
                )

            [round_trip_time] => 12
        )

)
```

Result *db.stats()*

```
{
        "db" : "dev",
        "collections" : 21,
        "objects" : 7153120,
        "avgObjSize" : 818.2133580871005,
        "dataSize" : 5852778336,
        "storageSize" : 6882250752,
        "numExtents" : 71,
        "indexes" : 26,
        "indexSize" : 866189968,
        "fileSize" : 8519680000,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Am I doing it wrong and what do I have to do, to get the statistics like db.stats()?

I'm using php 7.1 with the composer package mongodb/mongodb. The MongoDB has version 2.6.10.

<strike>The second problem, then I execute *$this->database->command(array('collStats' => "dev"));* i get a RuntimeException "Collection [dev.dev] not found.". Why?</strike>
*Found the reason for my RuntimeException... I requested "dev" as collectionname, but it's the name of the database.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $client = new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://host:27017");
    var_dump(iterator_to_array($client->database_name->command(array('dbStats' => 1))));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The iterator_to_array() function was the small but helpful tip. I found my mistake. I only looked on the result of the command, but did not go into the MongoDB\Driver\Cursor Object.

Comment: Do you also have an idea, why I get the RuntimeException?