# Simple HTTP/TCP health check for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, http, tcp

I need to create a Health Check for a MongoDB instance inside a Docker container.

Although I can make a workaround and use the Mongo Ping using the CLI, the best option is to create a simple HTTP or TCP testing. There is no response in the default 27017 port in standard ping testings.

Is there any trustworthy way to do it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I've created a simple health check for mongodb, it uses the `mongo` client to send a simple query request (eg. `db.stats()`) to the server.

```
$ mongo 192.168.5.51:30000/test

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3
connecting to: 192.168.5.51:30000/test

mongos> db.stats()
{
    "raw" : {
        "set1/192.168.5.52:27000,192.168.5.53:27000" : {
            "db" : "test",
            "collections" : 8,
            "objects" : 50,
            "avgObjSize" : 73.12,
            "dataSize" : 3656,
            "storageSize" : 53248,
            "numExtents" : 8,
            "indexes" : 8,
            "indexSize" : 65408,
            "fileSize" : 469762048,
            "nsSizeMB" : 16,
            "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 6
            },
            "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 28,
                "totalSize" : 184807424
            },
            "ok" : 1
        }
    },
    "objects" : 50,
    "avgObjSize" : 73,
    "dataSize" : 3656,
    "storageSize" : 53248,
    "numExtents" : 8,
    "indexes" : 8,
    "indexSize" : 65408,
    "fileSize" : 469762048,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 28,
        "totalSize" : 184807424
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You can also do this in one line:

```
$ echo 'db.stats().ok' | mongo 192.168.5.51:30000/test --quiet
1
```

Hope it's help.

**UPDATE:**

As @luckydonald said, the `ping` command is better, so you can do it like:

```
$ mongo --eval 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' localhost:27017/test --quiet
1
```

Thanks for @luckydonald.

Comment: Great! Solved my problem.

Comment: What if we want to check remote db, so without `mongo` binary, instead of local one?

Comment: _[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726152/mongodb-how-to-get-db-stats-from-api#comment13659027_8727314) warns:_
Be warned that dbstats blocks your database while it runs, so it's not suitable in production. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5714

Comment: A good alternative might be the [ping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/ping/) command.
As you might expect, it is intended to be lightweight and to return even from a server under heavy load which makes it well suited for a health check command[](https://serverfault.com/a/625493).
In pymongo  that's `db.command('ping')`, returning `{'ok': 1}`.

Comment: Tks guys, I was using db.stats() but now I'll switch to the ping command.

Comment: `db.stats()` may require authentication, you may get `{ok: 0}` despite Mongo is up an running.

Comment: the ping command takes 30 secs to timeout, how to adjust it? otherwise it's blocking the thread that sends the ping.

Answer (score 21):

If you need only a simple "ping" then you can also use `curl`:

```
curl --connect-timeout 10 --silent --show-error hostname:27017
```

If you get the "error" `It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.` then your MongoDB is running and replies.

Or use one of these

```
mongosh --norc --quiet --host=hostname:27017 <<< "db.getMongo()"
mongosh --norc --quiet --host=hostname:27017 --eval "db.getMongo()" 
echo "db.getMongo()" | mongosh --norc --quiet --host=hostname:27017
```

One benefit against `db.stats()`: Command `db.getMongo()` works without authentication, i.e. you don't need any credentials.

Just a note, if you run your MongoDB with SSL/TLS enabled and set `net.tls.mode: requireTLS` then you must also provide according certificates, otherwise you cannot run `db.getMongo()`, `db.runCommand("ping")` or `db.stats()`. The `curl` command is most generic and works in any case.

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to use a minimal MongoDB client written in a script language for which there is an interpreter in your container.

For example, here is a zero-dependency one in Python: [mongo_ping_client.py](https://github.com/Lucas-C/dotfiles_and_notes/blob/master/languages/python/mongo_ping_client.py)

Answer (score 1):

For MongoDB > 6.0 the healthcheck test could simply be :

```
test: mongosh --eval 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' --quiet
```

Answer (score 0):

```
telnet mongodb_server_name 28017
```

If the connection is successful, you will receive the following similar output from the command.

```
Trying 9.30.252.5...
Connected to 9.30.252.5.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If the connection is failed, you will receive the following similar output from the terminal.

```
Trying 9.30.252.5...
telnet: connect to address 9.30.252.5: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

[Font](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=sources-testing-network-connection-mongodb-rest-service-server)