# Adding a new Member in replica set mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

We are trying to add a new member in a replica set that are on different location and different data-center.
For EG: We are having 3 member replica set on US region and we need to add a member and arbiter on aws. We will be having 5 node with PSSSA. There is no any issue with connectivity we are able to ping and telnet all 5 server from US region to aws and vice-versa.
When we try to add the member it is showing as "**startup**" instead of "startup2" and data is also not syncing from US region data center to aws server.

MongoDB Version: 4.0.14

Comment: Ping and telnet (port 23) runs on different ports than mongoDB service (typically 27017). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63790795/3027266

Comment: Avoid arbiters at all costs.  It messes with writeConcern Majority if a data bearing region goes down

Comment: We are running mongo on 27018, and when we try to connect using telnet its working fine.

Comment: We need to migrate cluster to aws. to run the replica set with odd number we are using an arbiter. But even if i try to add an arbiter its showing as **startup**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your AWS node firewall! ;-)

You need to open a port for that node's own external IP address. This because node tries to connect itself, using that external address and if rules don't allow connection from that IP address to that same IP address, node cannot make the required connection.