# How can I check mongoDb Health check in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Is there any other way to check the health of MongoDB rather than using this.

```
@Override
public String mongoDbHealthCheck() {
    try {
        mongoTemplate.executeCommand("{ serverStatus: 1 }");
        return "Yes";
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        return "No";
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839365/simple-http-tcp-health-check-for-mongodb

Comment: I need it in Spring Boot

Comment: Are you using actuator? https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/ Mongo health check is included.

Comment: No I am not using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define it like this;

`management.health.mongo.enabled=true`

[Spring Boot Mongo health definiton](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.actuator.management.health.mongo.enabled)

Comment: Do we need to add this to application properties is that enough or need to implement any methods.

Comment: no need, just add this line.