# What's the best way to check if a mongo db in Atlas is reachable?

Tags: mongodb, azure, mongodb-atlas, health-check

I would like to monitor in Azure the external services i depend on to check if they are up and running, how can i check if my mongo instance on Atlas is working?

One way i found is to ping the database shards, they seem to reply 200 if they are up, is this the best way?
I also noticed that i can't ping shards for shared instances, is it true? (even though i don't need to check the shared instances, i just wanted to know)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script like this:

```
const map = db.adminCommand("getShardMap").map;
for (let aShard in map) {
   const uri = map[aShard].split('/');
   try {
      replicaSet = Mongo(`mongodb://username:password@${uri[1]}/admin?authSource=admin&replicaSet=${uri[0]}`).getDB('admin');
      let hello = replicaSet.hello();
      if (hello.isWritablePrimary) {
         print(`${aShard} is operational`)
      } else {
         print(`${aShard} has problems`)
      }
   } catch (err) {
      print(`${aShard} has problems: ${err.message}`)
   }
}
```

Depending on your requirements, you also use `replicaSet.adminCommand({ replSetGetStatus: 1 })` instead of `replicaSet .hello()` or evaluate other attributes of [db.hello()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/hello/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.hello)

If you like to check the hosts one by one, you can also use `db.adminCommand("getShardMap").hosts`

If you like to check only the entire database, have a look at [Simple HTTP/TCP health check for MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839365/simple-http-tcp-health-check-for-mongodb/63790795#63790795)

Comment: What if i don't want to write code? Is there something i can ping or configure in azure app insight?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't want to write code"? Calling a `ping` is also code (despite it is a bit shorter than my one). If you prefer to ping them one by one, it's up to you.