# Allow connection to mongo only from my server droplet

Tags: database, mongodb, ubuntu, digital-ocean, firewall

Recently I created a server with MongoDB preinstalled on a DigitalOcean droplet following these tutorials

- [DigitalOcean - Initial server setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-20-04)
- [DigitalOcean - How to secure MongoDB on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- [Medium - How to quickly setup MongoDB on DigitalOcean](https://medium.com/ninjaconcept/how-to-quickly-setup-mongodb-on-digitalocean-3d9791a7aaa4)

It was my first time doing this. Today I received this email from DigitalOcean:

> A recent network security scan suggests your Droplet `droplet-name` is
> running a MongoDB instance and that it may be unintentionally exposing
> data, or misconfigured to allow unauthorized access. MongoDB listens
> for traffic from everywhere on port 27107 and you can validate this
> report by attempting to connect to your MongoDB instance on via a
> simple telnet command: `telnet xxx.xxx.xx.xx 27107`
> If the connection is successful you will receive output like the following, which will confirm that your service is visible to the public Internet
>
> ```
> Trying xxx.xxx.xx.xx...
> Connected to xxx.xxx.xx.xx.
> ```
>
> Remediation of this issue will take just a few minutes and is
> relatively straightforward. You will need to open mongodb instance and
> run below command adding IP you want to connect from:
> `sudo mongod --bind_ip localhost, ip-or-Associated-Hostname-you-connect-from`

After connecting to my server, I tried `sudo mongod --bind_ip localhost` and `sudo mongod --bind_ip xxx.xxx.xx.xx` commands (xxx.xxx.xx.xx is my server IP, the one I have to put on `ssh user@xxx.xxx.xx.xx` command to connect to my server), but they didn't work, they threw me

```
I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=16339 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=host-name
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.3       
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc     
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:      
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64    
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64 
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "localhost" } }
E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

So I remembered my `mongod.conf` was:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security:
  authorization: enabled
```

I changed the `0.0.0.0` to `localhost,xxx.xxx.xx.xx`, and now when I try to connect with `telnet xxx.xxx.xx.xx 27107` (I didn't try this command before to check if the connection was successful, my bad) I receive

```
Connecting To xxx.xxx.xx.xx...Could not open connection to the host, on port 27107: Connect failed
```

My service is not visible to the public internet I guess (if I set again `bindIp: 0.0.0.0` I get the same output)

But I noticed DigitalOcean email telnet command says `27107` and all my settings (and DigitalOcean docs) are based on port `27017`. Is the email port wrong? If I put `telnet xxx.xxx.xx.xx 27017` the output is `Trying xxx.xxx.xx.xx...` and then the console is totally cleaned (even the prompt), and the title bar is changed to `Telnet xxx.xxx.xx.xx`. If I press a key nothing happens, but after pressing any key many times the console backs as it was at the beginning. I don't know if the connection is successful or not.

If I check `ufw status` as root, the output is

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     LIMIT       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
27017                      ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
27017 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I think this is not good.
If I try to connect to mongo on a Nodejs app running on my machine using `mongoose` with `mongodb://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:27017` the connection is successful, but when I try to create a new document, it throws `MongoServerError: command insert requires authentication` which looks good but I'm not sure.

What am I doing wrong? I want to allow connections to Mongo only from my pc and my Nodejs app, deployed on DigitalOcean via App Platform ([App Platform app doesn't have static IP address](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-identify-an-app-static-ip-address-or-range))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The advise from DigitalOcean is not very smart. There is no reason to run `mongod` as **root**. By running `sudo mongod ...` you ignore the settings in `mongod.conf`, which could be bad. From the log messages, it looks like you tried to start `mongod` while `mongod` service was already running. You can run `mongod` (with using the same port and/or `dbPath`) only once.

Now, regarding to your actual problem:

When you set `net.bindIp: localhost` (or `--bind_ip localhost`) then the `mongod` service is exposed only to the local machine, i.e. you cannot connect to the MongoDB from any external machine. This setting is typically used while maintenance work or when your MongoDB is accessed only from locally installed application - which seems to be your case.

When you set `net.bindIpAll: true` or `net.bindIp: 0.0.0.0` (or according command line options), then the `mongod` service is exposed to external network, i.e. you can connect from external machine to your MongoDB - provided the access is permitted by firewall settings.

Setting `net.bindIp: xxx.xxx.xx.xx` is more or less the same and actually only useful if your computer has multiple network interfaces. And of course, it works only if the machine has a static IP-Address.

You enabled [authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/authentication/), which is good. However, then must also connect with username/password *), either in [connection string](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/) or with [db.auth()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.auth/).

Note, you can (almost) **always** *connect* to a MongoDB without username/password. However, unless you are authenticated you can execute only harmless commands like `db.help()`, `db.version()`, `db.listCommands()`, etc. For other commands you get error `command ... requires authentication` as you saw it.

*) MongoDB also provides authentication via x.509 certificate, LDAP or Kerberos.

**Update:**

I missed your statement "I want to allow connections to Mongo only from my pc and my Nodejs app, deployed on DigitalOcean via App Platform"

In this case, you must expose the MongoDB to external, i.e. `net.bindIpAll: true`. When the MongoDB is visible public, then of course you must enable authentication. Which means you must connect with username/password. You should also use [TLS/SSL secured connections](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/).

Regarding firewall settings, it could be difficult. I guess, your PC does not have a static IP-Address. Thus the only option is `27017 ALLOW Anywhere`. Maybe you know the range on IP-Addresses your PC can have. Then you can open the firewall only for this particular range.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So are my settings good? I have doubts about ufw settings (`27017 ALLOW Anywhere`). I also noticed DigitalOcean email telnet command says `27107` and all the MongoDB documentation on DigitalOcean says `27017`. Is it wrong?

Comment: If I put telnet xxx.xxx.xx.xx 27017 looks like the connection is successfull, there's no output, but the console is cleaned.

Comment: I suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839365/simple-http-tcp-health-check-for-mongodb/63790795#63790795

Comment: If you set `net.bindIp: localhost` then firewall setting `27017 ALLOW Anywhere` has no effect, because mongod service is exposed only to the local machine. But in general you should open only the ports which are actually needed, thus it's better to remove this rule.

Comment: Default port for MongoDB is `27017`. Port 27107 seems to be a typo. Of course, in the end it is defined by your `net.port` setting.

Comment: I used that curl and received the output `It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.`. But I'm still not sure if my MongoDB is secure, because of the telnet response (I updated the question to give a little more details about it, the update is just before the `ufw status`)

Comment: Also I should remove both 27017 rules on ufw? Thanks

Comment: Please see up update

Comment: Thanks. I've looked into `mongod.conf` and `net.bindIp` is `0.0.0.0`, and I'm pretty sure the last time I've checked it was `localhost,xxx.xxx.xx.xx`, it's weird.

Also my Nodejs app deployed on DigitalOcean was connected to mongo (using user and password URI) when the setting was `localhost,xxx.xxx.xx.xx` and everything was working. If I understood correctly, it shouldn't have worked, right? Sorry for so many questions

Comment: When I understand your question correct, then everything was working fine. You only got a security alert from DigitalOcean. If you run your MongoDB with `authorization: enabled`, then everything is fine. As written, in order to increase security you may also use TLS/SSL certificates for connection or even better also for [authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/).

Comment: Yes, when I received the email everything was working fine, the `bindIp` was `0.0.0.0`, that was the reason of the alert I guess. And when I updated it to `localhost,xxx.xxx.xx.xx` everything kept working fine. The telnet response is what keeps me concerned. I will add TLS/SSL. Thanks so much.